# SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services avoid credentials prompt

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services. The problem is: whenever I am opening the ssrs local url in web browser, it is  prompting for credentials. Already tried editing the configuration settings. But still it is prompting. How to avoid this prompt? I am new to ssrs, so I need detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A browser prompt like that is going to be more of a client-side issue: their browsers security is configured in such a manner that it's not letting the webpage access local computer information.  This is not something you're going to be able to fix on the SSRS server, short of removing security entirely (bad idea).

Comment: Then Is there any client side solution to avoid this prompt (other than altering I.E trusted sites option.I need solution to be work across all browsers and across any client device(Linux,Windows,IOs,Android).

Comment: The client side fixes will be different on every browser - IE will be a trusted site, Chrome may actually inherit whatever settings you create on IE, or you can go to your security\intranet tab, Firefox requires editing your about:config, etc.  You could of course simply disable security/allow anonymous access to SSRS, but that's a really terrible idea.

Comment: Now i am asking just for test site,so please explain how to disable security or allow anonymous access in detailed steps.

Comment: Actually i am having an asp.net site where i want to render the ssrs report through the iframe tag.Is there any way to pass these credentials from my asp.net site to report server url via C# or VB coding?

Comment: Yes - there is a SOAP webservice behind SSRS ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155071.aspx ); you can make use of the LogonUser() method.